# git push to heroku asking for login but giving me error

Tags: heroku

On the command line, I run Heroku login and it brings me to my browser to login, which I do and the web page says I did successfully. But then my command line says:

```
Opening browser to https://cli-auth.heroku.com/auth/browser/9547a839-ddb8-4b50-a585-7f48c2d81c8a
Logging in... done
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:/Users/my-name/_netrc'
```

I open that file which contains a user name and password, it has one for "machine api.heroku.com" and one for "machine git.heroku.com". So I try to use "git push heroku master" and then I'm prompted for a user name and password, but neither of those work. I get:

```
remote: !       WARNING:
remote: !       Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: !       Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
```

Comment: I solved my own problem, will post answer in a minute

Comment: So it turns out that the last time I updated Heroku, the site automatically changed my API key for this particular app. Thus my new API key was not matching the old one in the _netrc file. The solution was to go to https://dashboard.heroku.com/account and scroll down to find the new API key. Use this as the password and email account as the user name and git push heroku master works again.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late, probably would help someone in the near future, another solution that worked is to delete the '_netrc' file in 'C:/Users/my-name/_netrc',
heroku needed to create a new '_netrc' file especially after upgrading, the file seemed to clash with the new heroku upgrade.

Comment: This worked for me.  Basically, the netrc file is a source heroku uses to authenticate you with.  If this is outdated, then it will give that error.  Delete it and try `heroku login`

Comment: to delete this file, make sure you allow/show hidden files, it should be there.

Answer (score -1):

Only works if command prompt is run as administrator.
Note: This solution is for windows operating system